# How do I add timezone offset to LocalDateTime object in Kotlin?

Tags: datetime, kotlin, timezone

I'm struggling to convert a LocalDateTime object which timezone is UTC to Korea Standard Time (KST, +09:00) and get a timestamp. I'd like to change `2021-04-20T03:00:00`(UTC) to `2021-04-20T12:00:00`(KST).

There is a UTC LocalDateTime object fetched from the database.

```kotlin
/*
+----+---------------------+
| id | created_at          |
+----+---------------------+
| 0  | 2021-04-20T03:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
*/

val createdAt: LocalDateTime = db.select(created_at).where(id.eq(0)) // 2021-04-20T03:00:00
```

Then, I tried to change the timezone of the object to KST(+09:00) using OffsetDateTime.

```kotlin
val kstCreatedAt = OffsetDateTime.of(createdAt, ZoneOffset.of("+9"))
                   // I expected this is 2021-04-20T12:00:00
```

My final goal is to get a timestamp of `2021-04-20T12:00:00`.

```kotlin
kstCreatedAt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() // 1618855200000 (The timestamp of 2021-04-20T03:00:00)
                     // I expected this is 1618887600000 (The timestamp of 2021-04-20T12:00:00)
```

I expected the variable `kstCreatedAt` to be `2021-04-20T12:00:00`, but it was still `2021-04-20T03:00:00`, and the last value was timestamp of `2021-04-20T03:00:00` not `2021-04-20T12:00:00`. How do I add timezone offset(+9) to the LocalDateTime object?

Comment: If you know the time-zone, why are you using a `LocalDateTime` instead of a `ZonedDateTime`?  You could then use e.g. `withZoneSameInstant()` to set a different time-zone without changing the instant — which I think is what you want.

Comment: LocalDateTime has no time zone, but you're treating it as if it's UTC. If it really is UTC, use ZonedDateTime for it as UTC, and then modify the time zone to KST.

Comment: Thank you, I did it: `ZonedDateTime.of(createdAt, ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Aisa/Seoul")) .toInstant().toEpochMilli()`. Can I solve this problem even if I'm not sure about its timezone?